# ATmega 32 Clock Frequency Issue

Tags: microcontroller, atmega, clock-speed

I'm currently using ATmega32 device with external clock speed of 16 MHz . the problem when i use a delay of for example 16,000 ms in the software, it actually delays only a 1000 ms in actual world. I mean the uC CPU divides the delay time by the clock frequency in MHz to make the delay (16,000 ms / 16 MHz). Also when i use a 8 MHz clock with the same amount of delay it would make a delay of 2,000 ms.
What would be the reason for that?

Edit "Here is my code"

```
include avr/io.h>

include util/delay.h>

include stdio.h>

include stdlib.h>


define F_CPU 16000000 

define BAUD 9600

define BRC  ((F_CPU/BAUD/16)-1)


void USART_Init(unsigned int brc)

{   

// set baud rate

    UBRRH = (unsigned char) (brc >> 8)  ;
    UBRRL = (unsigned char) brc ;

    UCSRB = (1 << TXEN ) | (1 << RXEN) ; // enable receiver and transmitter
    UCSRC = (0 << UMSEL); // setting Asynchronous mode
    UCSRC = (1 << UCSZ1) | (1 << UCSZ0); // set communication number of bits (8 in this case)
}

int main(void)
{


    USART_Init(BRC) ;
    while(1)
    {
        char c;

        _delay_ms(32000);
        for (int i=0 ; i<=3 ; i++)
        {
            if (UCSRA & (1 << UDRE))
            {

                UDR = i;
                _delay_ms(8000);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like your delay routine is anticipating a clock frequency of 1 MHz.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, but how to change that

Comment: I have defined in my code that FCPU is 16000000

Comment: Does your delay routine use that defined constant? Share the code for your delay function/macro, and we'll have a better chance of helping.

Comment: "I have defined in my code that FCPU is 16000000" - You have defined F_CPU _after_ including delay.h. Did the compiler give any warnings?

Comment: @ThePhoton  the delay routine uses a 1MHz F_CPU as Andy said but whenever I try to edit that I got a message that access to the path was denied. So how to make my delay routine use a 16MHz F_CPU ?

Comment: @BruceAbbott can you help please?

Comment: Move the line '#define F_CPU 16000000' up to the top of the file. Make sure that compiler optimization is turned on (eg. -Os). Read and respond to any compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `_delay_ms` to wait for that long. According to the [AVR GCC description](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__util__delay.html) of the function:

> The maximal possible delay is 262.14 ms / F_CPU in MHz.
>
> When the user request delay which exceed the maximum possible one, _delay_ms() provides a decreased resolution functionality. In this mode _delay_ms() will work with a resolution of 1/10 ms, providing delays up to 6.5535 seconds (independent from CPU frequency). The user will not be informed about decreased resolution.

Also, you should check that you set CLKDIV8 and CLKSEL correctly for your system.

Comment: in ATmega32 the CLKDIV8 fuse is not available, rather a fuse called BODLEVEL exists.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't sound like you have the "divide by system clock by 8" fuse set correctly, which is independent of the code.

Comment: In case of an accidentally set CLKDIV8 fuse, the actual delay would be longer than expected, not shorter. Also, the Atmega32 does not feature a clock division fuse.